# Bizarre HDBScan clustering result for cosine-similarity matrix

Tags: python, cosine-similarity, hdbscan

I'm trying to cluster similar messages within machine log files (where e.g. I can't ignore numbers). Debugging my code with a subset of messages which all have the same "*degree of similarity*" I came across a very strange finding: below a certain number of these messages HDBScan produces the expected result (which is all message belong to one or no cluster) but above a certain number of messages HDBScan suddenly starts finding different clusters which intuitively doesn't make sense to me.

And even more strange: that limit where I start seeing multiple clusters is 18 messages for the '*generic*' algorithm within HDBScan but 61 when using '*best*'. Well, maybe 'best' selects '*generic*' above 60 messages, not sure how to verify that...

I've tried various settings for `min_cluster_size` and `min_samples` and various distance metrics but the issue remains the same. Below please find some self-contained code to see if you can reproduce the issue. Just change `n_msg` to any `number >= 18` (or `>=61` when using '*best*') and you should get more than one cluster ID. The code also prints the cosine-similarity matrix so you can see how symmetrical this example is.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import hdbscan
import pandas as pd

# set number of dummy messages to be created
n_msg = 17

# create dummy messages with three identical and one variable term
msgs = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, n_msg):
    msg = ['bli bla blub ' + str(i)]
    msgs = msgs.append(msg)
msgs.columns = ['msg']

# tokenizer to split at space only so numbers will not be ignored
def space_tokenizer(msg):
   return msg.split()

# Vectorize dummy messages
TFvectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = space_tokenizer)
msgs_vect = TFvectorizer.fit_transform(msgs.msg)

# Compute cosine similarity between message vectors
msgs_CosSim = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(msgs_vect, msgs_vect))
print(msgs_CosSim,'\n')

# Cluster the cosine similarity results
hdbs = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=2, min_samples=1, metric='euclidean', \
                       algorithm='generic').fit(msgs_CosSim)
CosSim_clstr_ID = pd.DataFrame(hdbs.labels_)
CosSim_clstr_ID.columns = ['msg_ID']
print(CosSim_clstr_ID,'\n')

# Check number of cluster IDs generated
print('Number of cluster IDs:', len(CosSim_clstr_ID.msg_ID.unique()))
```

So again, with these dummy messages above I would expect the same result (all message belong to one cluster ID or the outlier cluster -1) independent from the number of messages but I start getting different clusters above a certain number of messages (depending on the algorithm choice within HDBScan).

Any idea what's going on?

Update: did some more research on this using `allow_single_cluster=True` only (!) and looped through all `algorithm` values as well as different message types (between one and four fixed terms plus the numbers) and here is the result where `'generic'`, whilst being the fastest, seems to be most likely to produce strange results randomly:
[image]

Comment: BTW, if you allow HDBScan to build single clusters via ````allow_single_cluster=True```` the problem is gone with these dummy messages at least...

Comment: More testing revealed that ````allow_single_cluster=True```` does not do the trick reliably...
If you make the messages shorter (````msg = ['bli ' + str(i)]````) and use ````algorithm='generic'```` already ````n_max = 10```` will produce a bizarre result where messages 0-3 and 6-9 are cluster ````0```` and messages 4-5 are outliers (cluster ````-1````)